# Retrieving a C- based struct from CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, opencv

I have been working on a project that uses C libraries, and my project needs to store some c structs in coredata. How can I do this by not transforming it to objective c object.

I want to store an Opencv struct(CvMat*).

```
/* binding stuff example*/
CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
// fill the matrix..
human.projVal = [NSData dataWithBytes:mat length:sizeof(mat)];
// then store it in core data
..  


/* retrieving stuff */
..
NSData *data = [[humansArray objectAtIndex:0] projVal];     
CvMat *mat = (CvMat *)[data bytes];
NSLog(@"cols =>> %i rows =>> %i",mat->cols,mat->rows);

for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {   
    NSLog(@"%f",mat->data.fl[i]);
}
```

when I try to retrieve the cvMat struct from coredata, I get weird cols and rows value and also data values. I cannot understand what is the problem.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as the underlying values and the re-create it.

Alternatively you could store it as a "Transformable" attribute. Core Graphics has something similar for various struct types such as CGRect. In the data model mark the type as "Transformable", then explicitly create the getters and setters in your entity class.

You'll need to create functions that transform the properties to a string as Core Graphics does, e.g. CGRectFromString and NSStringFromCGRect.

If you still want to store it as binary data, you may have more success encoding and decoding it using something like this described here in this link: [How to store custom objects with struct in Coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492449/how-to-store-custom-objects-with-struct-in-coredata).

Answer (score 0):

> ...my project needs to store some c
>   structs in coredata. How can I do this
>   by not transforming it to objective c
>   object.

You really can't do it reliably. Core Data stores objects and structs aren't objects. In principle, you can convert structs to data objects but that is a fragile solution owing to the way that different hardware interprets the data. If someone moves the store to another device, the structs may come out differently.

The safest solution is to simply write a transformer that converts the structs to object values and then back again. Say you had a struct with two int values. You would convert each int into a NSNumber, put those into an array and then store the array as an archive in a data attribute. Alternatively, you can create an entity that mimics the struct. I prefer the latter method.