# Issue with save file to Documents NSMutableArray with NSObjects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, ios-4.2

I'm a newbie iOS developer.
I wrote a small application that save an `NSMutableArray` array with my objects that derived from `NSObject`.
Application do the save but the file isn't created in document directory and application can't read.
this issue is both on the simulator and my iPhone 3gs 4.2.1

My `NSMutableArray` definition inside the `appDelegate` class:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *places;
```

My NSObject class:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Place : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *location;
}

-(id) init:(NSString *)name: (NSString *)location;

@property (retain,nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *name;
@property (retain,nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *location;

@end
```

My StorageService library class:

```
 #import "StorageService.h"


@implementation StorageService

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) saveArrayToFile:(NSString*) filename : (NSMutableArray *)arrayToSave{
    // get full path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fullPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    fullPath = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];  
    NSLog(@"Save in %@",fullPath);
    [arrayToSave writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
}

-(NSMutableArray*) readArrayFromFile:(NSString *)filename {
    // get full path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fullPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    fullPath = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        if (data == nil) {
            data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        NSLog(@"Read from %@",fullPath);
        return data;
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        return data;
    }
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

and My functions in the `appDelegate`:

```
    -(void) saveApplicationData {
    [self.storageService saveArrayToFile : PLACES_FILE : self.places];
}

-(void) loadApplicationData {
    self.places = [self.storageService readArrayFromFile:PLACES_FILE];
}
```

Here is my class that holds constant to filename:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const PLACES_FILE = @"Places.dat";

@interface ApplicationConstants : NSObject {

}

@end
```

So what is wrong?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to let `Place` conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, to allow for serialization to and from files *(and in memory data if wanted)*

Extend `Place` as *(I have also changed the name of the init method as your name was against every naming practice iOS has)*:

```
@interface Place : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *name; 
    NSString *location; 
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location;

@property (retain,nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *name; 
@property (retain,nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *location;

@end
```

Your implementation is quite simple but you also need to implement two methods defined by the `NSCoding` protocol:

```
@implementation Place

@synthesize name, location;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName location:(NSString *)aLocation {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = aName;
        self.location = aLocation;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithWithCoder:(NSCoder)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
       self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
       self.location = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"location";
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.location forKey:@"location"];
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
}

@end
```

With this in place, saving the `places` array to disk is as easy as:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:places toFile:path];
```

And decoding just as easy:

```
places = [[KSKeyUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path] retain];
```

Comment: Well, Thank you! it works! but my program crash when it save the data.
I needed to remove the initialization of the self super in the constructor of the Place class and the program save it successfuly!

Answer (score 2):

To use writeToFile objects in array need to be plist capable type (NSDate, NSDate, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary)

Implement NSCoding on the objects in array and use NSKeyedArchiver to serialize/deserialize.
write:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:self.places];
```

read:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

More info can be found here:

[Persisting Custom Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648143/best-method-of-persisting-custom-objects)